# Android - add image from a class to a layout

Tags: android, layout, bitmap

So basicaly the theory is this: i want to create a class that holds a bitmap, which is loaded from a resource. then i want to create a new object of that class and add it to a layout.

So far i've managed to do everything except idk, how to add the bitmap to a layout.

And i want it to be displayed on an existing layout.

bitmap class:

class BitmapView extends View 
{
    public BitmapView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wave);
 // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
}
```

}

and i call it with setContentView(new BitmapView(this));

but this draws the picture over the whole screen. i want it to display the background that was set in a previous layout. Also is there any way i can set bitmap size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Imageview for displaying bitmap

```
ImageView imgView=new ImageView(context);
imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
imgView.setBitmapImage(bitmap);   //Your bitmap goes here.
setContentView(imgView);
```

Comment: hmm ok how do i pass the context? btw this seems what i was looking for.

Comment: context is your activity instance itself... ImageView imgView=new ImageView(this); will work

Answer (score 0):

use  `setImageBitmap(bmp)`. Put an `ImageView` inside your layout. Reference it with `ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myBitmapId);`. When you create your bitmap simply do `im.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Comment: thanks, but i want to do it all programmaticaly without any xml. isn't findViewById only getting the ids that are set in layout.xml? idk im a nub